# ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 443/22: bad file number

Tags: git, bitbucket

I use Git with Bitbucket. The problem that I cann't push to Bit repo.

This is my config

```
Host bitbucket.org 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Port 443
```

Port 22 and 443 are the same error.

**Tried:**

I try to connect throught out company proxy like 10.x.x.x:3128, but still fail. 

Set http.proxy and https.proxy

```
git config --global http.proxy http://10.x.x.x:3128 
git config --global https.proxy http://10.x.x.x:3128
```

Anyone has ideas about that?

Comment: This is most likely an issue with your company's network filtering. Did you ask IT? Furthermore, can you include the commands that you're trying and output that it results in when you're connecting to the repository?

Comment: Hi @Joost, the above is command and error, you know when create repo on BitBucket with option use with existing local repo, it give us a couple command to init and make connection between local and remote repo.

Comment: The problem is come from ssh, when I try ssh -T git@bitbucket.org, it raises error. When searching around, I found out that it's due to firewall or proxy policy.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The error is "ssh connect to host bitbucket.org port 443 bad file number", if I change config file in .ssh folder, the error is "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host". This is my config file: ProxyCommand connect.exe -H http://10.9.x.x:3128 %h %p

Host bitbucket.org
User [username_login]
Hostname ssh.bitbucket.org
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Port 443